# Expanding jQuery if div word count is over word limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am after something similar to this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4CQt/

However, With a twist, what I would like to do is to have the content appear, and then when the content reaches 250 words (if words are not able to be done, a standard div min-height and increasing it upon click could work), I would like a 'Expand Content' or 'More' Button to appear, so the user can chose to click this and stretch out the content and read on, or to just scroll and see what is below.

Let me just note, I am not looking for the According jQuery, as I know this is a common recommendation for this sort of thing, but this will not work and will conflict with my Tab jQuery that is already on the page. The page is:

http://universitycompare.com/universities/anglia-ruskin-university/

As you can in the link above, the tab for 'overview' (scroll down) Has a lot of information and is about me controlling this so the user can read and see more of the information without scrolling.

```
Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code (stupid rule, thus this content in code).
```

Comment: The is a reason the rules are in place.   Your page will change over time, this future readers of this question will want to see the code, but it may not exist later.   Our goal here is to keep all questions and answers within the context of the site, so that people looking for answers later can use it as a reference.    If this is a problem... you might consider trying another site with a different help format.

Comment: Wow, this might as well be a forum, Why shall I do a question which is 4 times the length explaining the code on the jsFiddle? - It's ludicrous - I cannot find a working example of what I am after. Therefore the JSFiddle is to compliment my question, otherwise answers/other users may not understand the workings of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please read the "on hold" explanation below carefully. It explains "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/t4CQt/7/

```
var s = $("#aboutExpand").html();

if (s.split(' ').length > 250) {
    $("#aboutExpand").html(s.split(' ').slice(0,250).join(' ') + " ... " + '<a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>');
}

$("a.read-more").click(function() {
    $("#aboutExpand").html(s);
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, actually perfect, and I more than grateful! I do understand the jQuery but couldn't work out: 'if (s.split(' ').length > 250) {' - But thank you very much!